# jQuery outputs content. How to use JavaScript show hidden content when hovering over another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-audio

I have an HTML5 audio player that uses jQuery to output the player in Divs to control the audio. I'm trying to find a way to show a hidden div when you hover over another div.

The player is here: http://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/ryzqNJ and this is what triggers the audio player:

```
<audio src="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3" preload="auto" controls></audio>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/audio/js/audioplayer.js"></script>
<script>$( function() { $( 'audio' ).audioPlayer(); } );</script>
```

which outputs the following:

```
<div class="audioplayer audioplayer-stopped">
<audio src="audio.wav" preload="auto" controls></audio>
<div class="audioplayer-playpause" title="Play"><a href="#">Play</a></div>
<div class="audioplayer-time audioplayer-time-current">00:00</div>
<div class="audioplayer-bar">
    <div class="audioplayer-bar-loaded"></div>
    <div class="audioplayer-bar-played"><div class="player-button"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="audioplayer-time audioplayer-time-duration">&hellip;</div>
<div class="audioplayer-volume">
    <div class="audioplayer-volume-button" title="Volume"><a href="#">Volume</a></div>
    <div class="audioplayer-volume-adjust"><div><div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is located here:

```
<div class="audioplayer-bar-loaded"></div>
<div class="audioplayer-bar-played"><div class="player-button"></div></div>
```

The CSS is setup so that `.audioplayer-bar-loaded` and `.audioplayer-bar-played` are on top of each other and `.audioplayer-bar-played` has the highest `z-index`.

`.player-button` is hidden and I'm trying to find a way to show it when a user hovers over `.audioplayer-bar-loaded`. I've tried `.audioplayer-bar-loaded:hover ~ .player-button {visibility:visable}` and it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.audioplayer-bar-loaded:hover ~ .audioplayer-bar-played .player-button{visibility:visible}` as the selector since `.audioplayer-bar-loaded` and `.audioplayer-bar-played` are the siblings. And you misspelled "visible"

```js
/*
 By Osvaldas Valutis, www.osvaldas.info
 Available for use under the MIT License
*/

;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window,
    eStart = isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    eMove = isTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    eEnd = isTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup',
    eCancel = isTouch ? 'touchcancel' : 'mouseup',
    secondsToTime = function(secs) {
      var hoursDiv = secs / 3600,
        hours = Math.floor(hoursDiv),
        minutesDiv = secs % 3600 / 60,
        minutes = Math.floor(minutesDiv),
        seconds = Math.ceil(secs % 3600 % 60);
      if (seconds > 59) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = Math.ceil(minutesDiv);
      }
      if (minutes > 59) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours = Math.ceil(hoursDiv);
      }
      return (hours == 0 ? '' : hours > 0 && hours.toString().length < 2 ? '0' + hours + ':' : hours + ':') + (minutes.toString().length < 2 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) + ':' + (seconds.toString().length < 2 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);
    },
    canPlayType = function(file) {
      var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      return !!(audioElement.canPlayType && audioElement.canPlayType('audio/' + file.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() + ';').replace(/no/, ''));
    };

  $.fn.audioPlayer = function(params) {
    var params = $.extend({
        classPrefix: 'audioplayer',
        strPlay: 'Play',
        strPause: 'Pause',
        strRewind: 'Rewind',
        strForward: 'Forward',
        strSpeed: 'Speed',
        strMute: 'Mute',
        strVolume: 'Volume'
      }, params),
      cssClass = {},
      cssClassSub = {
        playPause: 'playpause',
        playing: 'playing',
        stopped: 'stopped',
        time: 'time',
        timeCurrent: 'time-current',
        timeDuration: 'time-duration',
        bar: 'bar',
        barLoaded: 'bar-loaded',
        barPlayed: 'bar-played',
        speed: 'speed',
        forward: 'forward',
        rewind: 'rewind',
        volume: 'volume',
        volumeButton: 'volume-button',
        volumeAdjust: 'volume-adjust',
        noVolume: 'novolume',
        muted: 'muted',
        muteButton: 'volume-off',
        mini: 'mini'
      };

    for (var subName in cssClassSub)
      cssClass[subName] = params.classPrefix + '-' + cssClassSub[subName];

    this.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() != 'audio')
        return false;

      var $this = $(this),
        audioFile = $this.attr('src'),
        isAutoPlay = $this.get(0).getAttribute('autoplay'),
        isAutoPlay = isAutoPlay === '' || isAutoPlay === 'autoplay' ? true : false,
        isLoop = $this.get(0).getAttribute('loop'),
        isLoop = isLoop === '' || isLoop === 'loop' ? true : false,
        isSupport = false;

      if (typeof audioFile === 'undefined') {
        $this.find('source').each(function() {
          audioFile = $(this).attr('src');
          if (typeof audioFile !== 'undefined' && canPlayType(audioFile)) {
            isSupport = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
      } else if (canPlayType(audioFile)) isSupport = true;

      var thePlayer = $('<div class="' + params.classPrefix + '">' + (isSupport ? $('<div>').append($this.eq(0).clone()).html() : '<embed src="' + audioFile + '" width="0" height="0" volume="100" autostart="' + isAutoPlay.toString() + '" loop="' + isLoop.toString() + '" />') + '<div class="' + cssClass.rewind + '" title="' + params.strRewind + '"><a href="#">-15</a></div><div class="' + cssClass.playPause + '" title="' + params.strPlay + '"><a href="#">' + params.strPlay + '</a></div><div class="' + cssClass.forward + '" title="' + params.strForward + '"><a href="#">+15</a></div></div>'),
        theAudio = isSupport ? thePlayer.find('audio') : thePlayer.find('embed'),
        theAudio = theAudio.get(0);

      if (isSupport) {
        thePlayer.find('audio').css({
          'width': 0,
          'height': 0,
          'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
        thePlayer.append('<div class="' + cssClass.time + ' ' + cssClass.timeCurrent + '"></div><div class="' + cssClass.bar + '"><div class="' + cssClass.barLoaded + '"></div><div class="' + cssClass.barPlayed + '"><div class="player-button"></div></div></div><div class="' + cssClass.time + ' ' + cssClass.timeDuration + '"></div><div class="' + cssClass.speed + '" title="' + params.strSpeed + '"><a href="#">1x</a></div><div  class="' + cssClass.muteButton + '" title="' + params.strMute + '"><a href="#">' + params.strMute + '</a></div><div class="' + cssClass.volume + '"><div class="' + cssClass.volumeButton + '" title="' + params.strVolume + '"><a href="#">' + params.strVolume + '</a></div><div class="' + cssClass.volumeAdjust + '"><div><div></div></div></div></div>');

        var theBar = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.bar),
          barPlayed = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.barPlayed),
          barLoaded = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.barLoaded),
          timeCurrent = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.timeCurrent),
          timeDuration = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.timeDuration),
          volumeButton = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.volumeButton),
          speed = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.speed),
          rewind = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.rewind),
          forward = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.forward),
          muteButton = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.muteButton),
          volumeAdjuster = thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.volumeAdjust + ' > div'),
          volumeDefault = 0,
          adjustCurrentTime = function(e) {
            theRealEvent = isTouch ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] : e;
            theAudio.currentTime = Math.round((theAudio.duration * (theRealEvent.pageX - theBar.offset().left)) / theBar.width());
          },
          adjustVolume = function(e) {
            theRealEvent = isTouch ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] : e;
            theAudio.volume = Math.abs((theRealEvent.pageY - (volumeAdjuster.offset().top + volumeAdjuster.height())) / volumeAdjuster.height());
          },
          updateLoadBar = function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
              if (theAudio.buffered.length < 1) return true;
              barLoaded.width((theAudio.buffered.end(0) / theAudio.duration) * 100 + '%');
              if (Math.floor(theAudio.buffered.end(0)) >= Math.floor(theAudio.duration)) clearInterval(interval);
            }, 100);
          };

        var volumeTestDefault = theAudio.volume,
          volumeTestValue = theAudio.volume = 0.111;
        if (Math.round(theAudio.volume * 1000) / 1000 == volumeTestValue) theAudio.volume = volumeTestDefault;
        else thePlayer.addClass(cssClass.noVolume);

        timeDuration.html('&hellip;');
        timeCurrent.html(secondsToTime(0));

        theAudio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
          updateLoadBar();
          timeDuration.html($.isNumeric(theAudio.duration) ? secondsToTime(theAudio.duration) : '&hellip;');
          volumeAdjuster.find('div').height(theAudio.volume * 100 + '%');
          volumeDefault = theAudio.volume;
        });

        theAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
          timeCurrent.html(secondsToTime(theAudio.currentTime));
          barPlayed.width((theAudio.currentTime / theAudio.duration) * 100 + '%');
        });

        theAudio.addEventListener('volumechange', function() {
          volumeAdjuster.find('div').height(theAudio.volume * 100 + '%');
          if (theAudio.volume > 0 && thePlayer.hasClass(cssClass.muted)) thePlayer.removeClass(cssClass.muted);
          if (theAudio.volume <= 0 && !thePlayer.hasClass(cssClass.muted)) thePlayer.addClass(cssClass.muted);
        });

        theAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
          thePlayer.removeClass(cssClass.playing).addClass(cssClass.stopped);
        });

        theBar.on(eStart, function(e) {
            adjustCurrentTime(e);
            theBar.on(eMove, function(e) {
              adjustCurrentTime(e);
            });
          })
          .on(eCancel, function() {
            theBar.unbind(eMove);
          });

        volumeButton.on('click', function() {
          if (thePlayer.hasClass(cssClass.muted)) {
            thePlayer.removeClass(cssClass.muted);
            theAudio.volume = volumeDefault;
          } else {
            thePlayer.addClass(cssClass.muted);
            volumeDefault = theAudio.volume;
            theAudio.volume = 0;
          }
          return false;
        });

        volumeAdjuster.on(eStart, function(e) {
            adjustVolume(e);
            volumeAdjuster.on(eMove, function(e) {
              adjustVolume(e);
            });
          })
          .on(eCancel, function() {
            volumeAdjuster.unbind(eMove);
          });

        var currentSpeedIdx = 0;
        var speeds = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
        thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.speed).on('click', function() {
          currentSpeedIdx = currentSpeedIdx + 1 < speeds.length ? currentSpeedIdx + 1 : 0;
          theAudio.playbackRate = speeds[currentSpeedIdx];
          this.textContent = speeds[currentSpeedIdx] + 'x';
          return false;
        });

        thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.rewind).on('click', function() {
          theAudio.currentTime -= 15;
          return false;
        });

        thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.forward).on('click', function() {
          theAudio.currentTime += 15;
          return false;
        });

        muteButton.on('click', function() {
          if (theAudio.muted) {
            theAudio.muted = false;
          } else {
            theAudio.muted = true;
          }
          return false;
        });
      } else thePlayer.addClass(cssClass.mini);

      thePlayer.addClass(isAutoPlay ? cssClass.playing : cssClass.stopped);

      thePlayer.find('.' + cssClass.playPause).on('click', function() {
        if (thePlayer.hasClass(cssClass.playing)) {
          $(this).attr('title', params.strPlay).find('a').html(params.strPlay);
          thePlayer.removeClass(cssClass.playing).addClass(cssClass.stopped);
          isSupport ? theAudio.pause() : theAudio.Stop();
        } else {
          $(this).attr('title', params.strPause).find('a').html(params.strPause);
          thePlayer.addClass(cssClass.playing).removeClass(cssClass.stopped);
          isSupport ? theAudio.play() : theAudio.Play();
        }
        return false;
      });

      $this.replaceWith(thePlayer);
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.audioplayer-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px
}

.audioplayer-bar-loaded {
  background: grey;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9
}

.audioplayer-bar-played {
  background: #aa0000;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99
}

.player-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  float: right;
  width: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000
}

.audioplayer-bar-loaded:hover ~ .audioplayer-bar-played .player-button {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<audio src="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3" preload="auto" controls></audio>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('audio').audioPlayer();
  });
</script>
```